# Работа с URL

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Доброго времени суток. Хотелось бы узнать, как можно обновить текущий URL страницы, после выполнения AJAX запроса. Допустим текущий адрес

```
http://mysite.ru/menu/
```

После загрузки страницы адрес должен стать

```
http://mysite.ru/users/
```

Делаю через `history.pushState`, но адрес становится

```
http://mysite.ru/menu/users/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
history.pushState(null, null, 'http://mysite.ru/users/');
```

Comment: Всего-то)) А я голову ломал) Спасибо =)

Comment: @Glorymirror, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).